# Java 1.6, How to get total bytes used by everything within a specified directory

Tags: java

Let's say you have multiple directories that all exist on the same partition. Let's say you want to find the total bytes used by everything within each directory, whats a good way to do that? Looking at Java File and Apache FileUtils I can only get disk usage information about the partition, but what I need is to be able to limit that down to a specified directory.

```
Example:

    Partition X: 100GB

    Root directories:

    /x/1/
    /x/2/
    /x/3/

Deeper directories can exist under each root directory:

/x/1/files/a/deeper/path/test.txt
    /x/2/files/test.txt
    /x/3/files/path/to/files/test.txt

Goal:

long byteSumForX1 = ??
```

Say the 3 above paths exist under partition x, i'd like to be able to find the total bytes used by each root directory specified above. The total would need to be recursive and include all files and directories within the root directory

Any ideas? I'd prefer to leverage some existing library for this, if one exists (assuming/hoping it does)

Comment: Most tools only give you the length of the files, not the size actually used. For example, a file of 1 byte can use 512B or 4KB of disk space.  Files with longer names can use more disk space (depending on the file system type) If you have a sparse file, its length can to be many times (possibly 1000x bigger) than the size actually used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ths simplest solution would be to use the [sizeOfDirectory()](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#sizeOfDirectory(java.io.File)) method, found in the `FileUtils` class of Apache Commons. Quoting the javadocs:

> Counts the size of a directory recursively (sum of the length of all files).
>
> Parameters: directory - directory to inspect, must not be null
>
> Returns: size of directory in bytes, 0 if directory is security restricted